# Vectorizing Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm dealing with a Pandas dataframe with a column that exists of textual descriptions. This column needs to be transformed into something that works with a Support Vector Machine, specifically `sklearn SVC`. So I want to take each description and replace it with numerical data, for this I'm using the TfidfVectorizer.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
df['description'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'])
```

This results in records looking like the following:

```
0         (0, 12)\t0.30879049244590173\n  (0, 333)\t0....
```

What this is returning is close but still not usable in an SVM. I suspect I'm misunderstanding how `sklearn` deals with `Pandas`

Comment: A copy-pastable [mcve] would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The output of `vectorizer.fit_transform()` is a **2-d array**. Storing a 2-d array in a single column of DataFrame is not good, will result in issues.
2. The output of `vectorizer.fit_transform()` is a **sparse** 2-d array, to save memory. Since the vocabulary is large and most documents will contain only some words from the whole vocabulary, the actual output array contains large number of zero-values elements. Sparse matrices are a way to handle those.

   `pandas`  generally don't work well with sparse arrays. It sees that as a single object. So when you do:

   ```
   df['description'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'])
   ```

   will broadcast the single object (our sparse matrix) into each position (row) of that specified column. So that is not correct.

If you can work with sparse matrices then you should for your further processing as @AI_Learning mentioned.

If you absolutely need to store the tf-idf values into a DataFrame for display or saving purposes, the correct way would be to create a new DataFrame:

```
sparse_out = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'])
tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(data = sparse_out.toarray(),
                        columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names())

tfidf_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can't store the output of **`tf-idf vectorizer`** in a nice way. Hence save it separately (`transformed_text`) and then feed it to svm.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
transformed_text = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['description'])

model=svm.SVC()
model.fit(transformed_text)
```